# How to fetch the value of a column in a table present sql developer through java script

Tags: javascript

Need to fetch a value from a column in a table present in SQL developer through Javascript

The table [AAAA] consist of four columns A , B , C and D.
How should i write the javascript to fetch the value of a record in column C by searching with a specific record value from column B

select C from AAAA where B = '3'; -- where 3 is a record from column B 
How to obtain it through javascript

Need to fetch those values through intershop

Comment: Are you going to run the JS in a browser?

Comment: You will have to fetch that complete record i.e all columns A,B,C,D for particular Row. Once you have those values you could easily access them or you can use fetch once again

Comment: need to fetch those values through intershop

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to SQL Developer directly from client side Java Script, but only from server side Java Script, such as Node JS.
Write a server side Java Script Code to connect to your database and then create APIs from the same. 
Retrieve the values by invoking APIs from client side Java Script.

Answer (score 0):

for the fetching database, you required server-side interaction.